# Symfony2 Doctrine проверка уникальности индекса

Tags: php, symfony2, doctrine2

Ребят есть вот такой индекс

```
/**
* PriceSelectedHotels
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PriceSelectedHotelsRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="price_selected_hotels", indexes={
 *     @ORM\Index(name="idx_price_selected_hotels_date_city", columns={"check_in_date", "city_code"}),
 * })
 */
```

надо как то проверять что новая запись в базу уникальная по этому индексу

Answer (score 2):

Такая конструкция убивает сразу двух зайцев: она и навешивает уникальный индекс в БД, и добавляет правило валидации для форм:

```
/**
* PriceSelectedHotels
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PriceSelectedHotelsRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="price_selected_hotels", uniqueConstraints={
 *     @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="idx_price_selected_hotels_date_city", columns={"check_in_date", "city_code"}),
 * })
 */
```

Можно так же сделать это по отдельности: создать уникальный индекс (как в самом вопросе, но с флагом `unique = true`) и затем уже навешать валидацию [UniqueEntity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html).